# Motion/Moving effect with animation on still image

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation, core-image, glkit

I am trying to implement animation in a still image in a user-guided direction, something like this:

**Original image**

[image: original image]

**Expected result**

[image: expected result]

For this, I have tried the `CIBumpDistortionLinear` `CIFilter`. It is animating, but the animation is not exactly like that.

```
let bumpDistortionLinearParams: [String: AnyObject] = [
    kCIInputImageKey: coreImage!,
    "inputCenter" : CIVector(string: coordStr),
    "inputRadius": 300.0 as AnyObject,
    "inputAngle" : 90.0 as AnyObject,
    "inputScale" : 0.1 as AnyObject
]

let bumpDistortionLinear = CIFilter(name: "CIBumpDistortionLinear", parameters: bumpDistortionLinearParams)
```

Comment: Is this possible with MetalKit via creating shader on image? Is this resolved for you?

Comment: It is possible with Metal Kit. I am looking for similar effect with shader for which selected draw area will not animate (similar to masking in plotaverse). Any Idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can use SpriteKit with SKTexture / SKTextureAtlas.
Small example:
https://www.raywenderlich.com/144-spritekit-animations-and-texture-atlases-in-swift

**Update:**
If you need dynamic animation, you can make solution base on Metal
Example:
https://github.com/KrisYu/Water
Metal tutorial:
http://metalkit.org/

Comment: I'll need to implement that dynamically on any user captured photo. Does SKTexture will help on it. if you think so, can you provide any example or code ref.

Comment: @Arvind If you need dynamic animation, you can use Metal.   
It maybe help:    
https://github.com/KrisYu/Water  
SKTexture can’t do this (or I don’t known how)

Comment: @Eysner: I am looking for similar animation on different images. That is not exactly the water effect. The animation will be in user guided direction. You can try on https://plotaverse.com for better understanding.